# Group list items based on common sliced text of items

Tags: python

I have the list below i want to group based on  the '2020.0x' slice of the texts.

```
mylist = ['c-2020.09.25.tif', 'c-.2020.09.12.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.09.13.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.09.26.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.08.11.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.07.24.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.07.16.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.07.09.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.08.21.masked.tif', 'c-.2020.8.09.masked']
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
import itertools
key = lambda x: x[2:9] 
 

for key, group in itertools.groupby(mylist, key):
    print([str(list(group))])
```

But I am having a messy result, nothing like I was expecting. Any idea is welcome!

Comment: You need to do `mylist = sorted(mylist, key=key)` before the `groupby`.

Comment: Try this: `def key(x): year, month, day, *rest = x.split('-')[1].lstrip('.').split('.'); return year, month` which removes the `c-` or `c-.` and then turns the rest into a tuple like `("2020", "09", "25", "masked", "tif")` and then returns only the first two items of that tuple

Comment: i strongly recommend not using a variable name as `key` when you want to pass it to `key`. Don't stress out python :) use another variable name instead :)

Comment: @JoeFerndz your comment is misplaced, `key` is not the name of a builtin function (or keyword) so you can use it just fine, but a name like `get_year_and_month()` might make it easier to understand.

Comment: your last value does not have leading zero `cc-.2020.8.09.masked'`. Is this expected? Assume we need to group this along with 2020.08. Also the data has `cc-` compared to others that have just `c-`. Is that expected?

Comment: @Boris That is it. Thanks! I will answer with your input

Comment: @JoeFerndz it was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @Boris - `key` is not the name of a builtin, but it is used for two different things in the same part of the code; first for the function, then immediately after for unpacking the tuple in the `for` loop. That's very confusing and likely to lead to errors (eg. if the `key` function is needed again later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort the input to groupby, otherwise the groups will be separated by other groups (this works the same way as `sort` and `uniq` in bash). Furthermore, your `key=` function needs to handle the filename starting with "`c-.`" and "`c-`" without the dot.

```py
import itertools

def get_year_and_month(filename):
    year, month, day, *rest = filename.split('-')[1].lstrip('.').split('.')
    return int(year), int(month)  # convert to int to handle missing leading 0
 
mylist = sorted(mylist, key=get_year_and_month)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=get_year_and_month):
    print(list(group))
```